# IE filter to set a image as background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use the following code in css in order to set a image as the background of a div, and the image size will be same as the size of div. it worked fine in home page, but if i go to any inside page
, it just cant load the image, any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

```
.navLogo{width:100%; height:110px; background-image:url('images/navlogo.png'); background-size: 100% 100%; background: none\9; filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(sizingMethod='scale',src='template/default/css/images/navlogo.png');}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z33a44k3/) with Internet Explorer and it shows the image correctly.

As you can check I've used two different borders to show that the inner div is the one with the background applied to it.

It should work even without any IE filter, just use this

```
.navLogo{
    background-image:url('http://doc.jsfiddle.net/_downloads/jsfiddle-logo.png');
}
```

And you should be ok. Just let us know if you encounter any other problem.